# Can I have my options menu display only on one tab rather than all three in my Tkinter gui?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am programming a GUI with three tabs - each tab needs to have its own dropdown menu to select a financial calculation to compute. I have coded an options menu but it appears in all three tabs rather than one. How can I make an options menu exclusive to one tab? After trying to put the options menu in a frame my code looked like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

variable = StringVar(root)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0])

w = OptionMenu(root, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.pack()

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl, OPTIONS=["Gross Margin", "Operating Margin", "Net Profit Margin"])
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='Tab 3')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

ttk.Label(tab1,
          text="Welcome to GeeksForGeeks").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab2,
          text="Lets dive into the world of computers").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab3,
          text="My third tab for my coursework").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

but I still get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fariz/PycharmProjects/Practice/venv/bin/CW1 B + Fin Comp..py", line 18, in <module>
    tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl, OPTIONS=["Gross Margin", "Operating Margin", "Net Profit Margin"])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/ttk.py", line 742, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/ttk.py", line 559, in __init__
    tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2296, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-OPTIONS"
```

Comment: Put the `OptionMenu` inside the frame instead of root window.

Comment: @acw1668 how would I put it in the frame? I keep getting errors when I put it in

Comment: Update your question with the error full traceback.

Comment: @acw1668 I have updated it now..any thoughts?

Comment: *"Put the `OptionMenu` inside the frame"* means `w = OptionMenu(tab1, ...)`.  Of course you need to put this line after creating `tab1`.  Also make sure you used the same layout function on `w` as there is another label inside that frame.

Answer (score 1):

The following code moves the option menu in to tab 1.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab Widget")
tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)


tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)

tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')
tabControl.add(tab3, text='Tab 3')
tabControl.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

OPTIONS=["Gross Margin", "Operating Margin", "Net Profit Margin"]
variable = tk.StringVar(root)
variable.set(OPTIONS[0])
w = tk.OptionMenu(tab1, variable, *OPTIONS)
w.grid(column=0,row=1)

ttk.Label(tab1,
          text="Welcome to GeeksForGeeks").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab2,
          text="Lets dive into the world of computers").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)
ttk.Label(tab3,
          text="My third tab for my coursework").grid(column=0, row=0, padx=30, pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```